# Loop in hash for ruby

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
blockchain = [
  { from_user: nil, to_user: "brian", amount: 21000 },
  { from_user: "brian", to_user: "ben", amount: 9000 },
  { from_user: "brian", to_user: "jeff", amount: 7000 },
  { from_user: "ben", to_user: "jeff", amount: 400 },
  { from_user: "brian", to_user: "jeff", amount: 1500 },
  { from_user: "jeff", to_user: "brian", amount: 4500 },
  { from_user: "jeff", to_user: "ben", amount: 1750 }
]
```

I want to get the final amounts for each person, total but coin remaining. It should print out:

```
Brian's balance is 8000
Ben's balance is 10350
Jeff's balance is 2650
```

I am trying to figure out how to write the code. Could someone help?

Comment: Show us your effort. Have you tried something?

Comment: Hint: [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and some math.

Comment: Yes I have tried. Here is my attempt,

Comment: For
puts "Brian’s balance is #{blockchain[:from_user][Brain][:group by} && .do + from_user
end

Comment: I only tried Brian because if I can get Brian then the rest are the same logic

Comment: will anyone please help?

Comment: @John check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Create an empty hash with a default value of zero**

The keys of this hash will be the users and whose values will be the amounts each user has at any given time.

For a hash `h` to have a default value of `0` means that `h[k]` returns `0` if `h` does not have a key `k`. Here we will be writing `h[k] += 1`, which expands to

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

If (before this expression is executed) `h` does not have a key `k` `h[k]` on the right returns zero, so we have

```
h[k] = 0 + 1
  #=> 1
```

Thereafter, `h[k]` on the right will be a positive integer.

If you are wondering why `h[k]` on the left of the expression does not return `0`, recall that `h[k] = h[k] + 1` is syntactic sugar for the actual expression

```
h.[]=(h.[](k) + 1)
```

We have the method `[]=` on the left and the method `[]` on the right. It is `h.[](k)` that returns the default value when `h` does not have a key `k`.

Find a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html) method `m` (not actually "m") to do that.

```
h = Hash.m(?)
```

The question mark means that you must supply an argument for the method `m`.

**Step 2: Step through the hashes in `blockchain` to update the hash `h`**

```
blockchain.each do |g|
  h[?] += ?
  h[?] -= ? unless ? == nil
end

h #=> {"brian"=>8000, "ben"=>10350, "jeff"=>2650}
```

We now have the information needed to print the desired results.

In practice we would chain these two steps using the method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html):

```
blockchain.each_with_object(Hash.m(?)) do |g,h|
  h[?] += ??
  h[?] -= ?? unless ?? == nil
end
  #=> {"brian"=>8000, "ben"=>10350, "jeff"=>2650}
```

Here `?` and `??` are respectively placeholders for an argument and an expression.

Comment: You did not provide solution, instead provided way to find it and made OP to learn. Appreciated! +1 for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way :

```
blockchain = [
  { from_user: nil, to_user: "brian", amount: 21000 },
  { from_user: "brian", to_user: "ben", amount: 9000 },
  { from_user: "brian", to_user: "jeff", amount: 7000 },
  { from_user: "ben", to_user: "jeff", amount: 400 },
  { from_user: "brian", to_user: "jeff", amount: 1500 },
  { from_user: "jeff", to_user: "brian", amount: 4500 },
  { from_user: "jeff", to_user: "ben", amount: 1750 }
]

users = {}

blockchain.each do |block|
    users[block[:from_user]] = 0 if !users.keys.include?(block[:from_user]) && block[:from_user].present?
    users[block[:to_user]] = 0 if !users.keys.include?(block[:to_user])

    users[block[:to_user]] = users[block[:to_user]] + block[:amount]
    users[block[:from_user]] = users[block[:from_user]] - block[:amount] if block[:from_user].present?
end

puts users
```

The `users` hash will contain your required output

```
{"brian"=>8000, "ben"=>10350, "jeff"=>2650}
```

Comment: This does not work in pure Ruby because Ruby does not have a method `present?`. Luckily, the fix is easy: just remove the two instances of `.present?`! While you're at it I suggest you format your code so that we don't have to scroll horizontally to read it. I would also suggest `unless users...` rather that `if !users...`, but that's a stylistic issue.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.. I am just contributing since yesterday.. havent got a hang of it yet. And he has tagged the question as Ruby on Rails.. so `.present?` should not cause any issue.

Comment: I missed the Rails tag. I was going by the first sentence in @Kamal's answer and `present?` was the only non-Ruby method. I should have checked the tags with the question, of course; don't know why I didn't. Anyway, my apologies for that. btw, if you write `users = Hash.new(0)` (giving `users` a default value of zero, you can remove the first two lines in the block. Also, you can simplify `users[block[:to_user]] = users[block[:to_user]] + block[:amount]` to `users[block[:to_user]] += block[:amount]` (etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Below is **simple implementation** to achieve balance for each person,

```
add = blockchain.group_by { |x| x[:to_user] }.reject { |k,v| k.nil? }.transform_values { |v| v.map { |x| x[:amount] }.sum }
# => {"brian"=>25500, "ben"=>10750, "jeff"=>8900}
sub = blockchain.group_by { |x| x[:from_user] }.reject { |k,v| k.nil? }.transform_values { |v| v.map { |x| x[:amount] }.sum }
# => {"brian"=>17500, "ben"=>400, "jeff"=>6250}

people = (add.keys + sub.keys).uniq
# => ["brian", "ben", "jeff"]

people.each { |x| puts "#{x.capitalize}'s balance is #{add[x].to_i - sub[x].to_i}" }

# Brian's balance is 8000
# Ben's balance is 10350
# Jeff's balance is 2650
# => ["brian", "ben", "jeff"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome answer by Amogh Hegde, but somehow It was not working on my system with ruby 2.5.1 but if you add  `require 'active_support/all'` on the top script, it will work. But I tried to do it without including anything. So have done very minor change. Following is the complete code I just changed if condition to check `:from_user` is present or not, so I have converted to a string and then checked it with the empty method.

```
blockchain = [
  { from_user: nil, to_user: "brian", amount: 21000 },
  { from_user: "brian", to_user: "ben", amount: 9000 },
  { from_user: "brian", to_user: "jeff", amount: 7000 },
  { from_user: "ben", to_user: "jeff", amount: 400 },
  { from_user: "brian", to_user: "jeff", amount: 1500 },
  { from_user: "jeff", to_user: "brian", amount: 4500 },
  { from_user: "jeff", to_user: "ben", amount: 1750 }
]

users = {}

blockchain.each do |block|
    users[block[:from_user]] = 0 if !users.keys.include?(block[:from_user]) && !block[:from_user].to_s.empty?
    users[block[:to_user]] = 0 if !users.keys.include?(block[:to_user])
    users[block[:to_user]] = users[block[:to_user]] + block[:amount]
    users[block[:from_user]] = (users[block[:from_user]] - block[:amount]) if !block[:from_user].to_s.empty?
end

puts users
```

I am getting following response.

```
{"brian"=>8000, "ben"=>10350, "jeff"=>2650}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In one iteration:**

```
blockchain.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |h, nh|
  nh[h[:from_user]] -= h[:amount]
  nh[h[:to_user]] += h[:amount]
end

#=> {nil=>-21000, "brian"=>8000, "ben"=>10350, "jeff"=>2650}
```

---

To keep track of the full movements:

```
blockchain.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }) do |h, nh|
  nh[h[:from_user]][:out] -= h[:amount]
  nh[h[:to_user]][:in] += h[:amount]
end


#=> {nil=>{:out=>-21000}, "brian"=>{:in=>25500, :out=>-17500}, "ben"=>{:in=>10750, :out=>-400}, "jeff"=>{:in=>8900, :out=>-6250}}
```

---

**Other option:** could calculate incomes and outcomes using [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [`Hash#transform_values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), then merge together.

Incomes are:

```
incomes = blockchain.group_by { |k,v| k[:to_user] }.transform_values{ |a| a.sum { |h| h[:amount] }}
#=> {"brian"=>25500, "ben"=>10750, "jeff"=>8900}
```

Outcomes are (negatives):

```
outcomes = blockchain.group_by { |k,v| k[:from_user] }.transform_values{ |a| -a.sum { |h| h[:amount]}}
#=> {nil=>-21000, "brian"=>-17500, "ben"=>-400, "jeff"=>-6250}
```

Then merge passing a block using [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

```
incomes.merge(outcomes) { |k, income, outcome| income + outcome }
#=> {"brian"=>8000, "ben"=>10350, "jeff"=>2650, nil=>-21000}
```

---

Comment: Updated also with an example to track the movements in/out of each member